# What should be the output shape of the loss function in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

For example, if I'm doing image prediction and output of my network is tensor of shape `[299, 299, 3]` how do I write loss function `loss(y_true, y_pred)`. Should I expect `y_true` and `y_pred` to have shape `[batch_size, 299, 299, 3]` and output of the loss function to be array of the shape `[batch_size]` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *My first answer was written thinking your input was (299,299,3), not your output. My apologies! "Image prediction" is rather vague, but if your intention really is to output a 3D tensor as your `y_pred`, you still will probably want to create a loss function that produces a scalar. This is because the loss of a sample needs to be pooled with the error of all the other samples. The joint loss allows the model to generalize its behavior. See [this wiki snippet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation#Assumptions). Essentially, a multidimensional loss function would be equivalent to setting the batch size to 1 in stochastic gradient descent.*

**First Answer:**
Usually you want your loss function to output a single number. If you're doing image classification, you almost certainly want your loss function to output a single number.

Assuming "image prediction" means "image classification" your inputs are likely going to be your images and your `y_pred` will most often be a batch of one dimensional arrays with a length equal to the number of possible classes.

Your `y_true` will be batch of one_hot encoded arrays of the same size as `y_pred`. This means that they are arrays with a length equal to the number of classes your images can be. The difference is that the `y_true` vectors contain all zeros except for a single 1 at the index of the corresponding image's category.

For example, if your images are only of dogs, cats, or sheeps, then there are 3 possible classes. Let's arbitrarily say that a 0 means dog, 1 means cat, and 2 means sheep. Then if an image is of a sheep, the corresponding `y_true` would be [0,0,1]. If the image is of a cat, `y_true` would be [0,1,0]. If your image is of a bear, your classifier will be confused...

As for the loss function, usually you would somehow figure out how far off each `y_pred` is from the corresponding `y_true` and sum up all of the differences in the batch. This results in a single number representing the total loss for the batch.

Keras is set up nicely to handle the loss function for you. When you have a model, you call `model.compile(loss='some_loss_fxn_here', optimizer='some_optimizer_here')` and specify the loss function you want to use as a string. You will probably want to use `'categorical_crossentropy'`.

Given the way you worded your question, you may need to create a model before worrying about all of this.

You might try something like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

def conv_block(x, depth, filt_shape=(3,3), padding='same', act='relu'):
    x = Conv2D(depth, filt_shape, padding=padding, activation=act)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    pool_filt, pool_stride = (2,2), (2,2)
    return MaxPooling2D(pool_filt, strides=pool_stride, padding='same')(x)

# Don't forget to preprocess your images!
inputs = Input(shape(299,299,3))
layer1 = conv_block(inputs, 64) # shape = [batch_size,150,150,64]
layer1 = Dropout(.05)(layer1) # Note early dropout should be low
layer2 = conv_block(layer1, 64) # shape = [batch_size,75,75,64]
layer2 = Dropout(.1)(layer2)
layer3 = conv_block(layer2, 64) # shape = [batch_size,38,38,64]
layer3 = Dropout(.2)(layer3)
layer4 = conv_block(layer3, 64) # shape = [batch_size,19,19,64]
layer4 = Dropout(.25)(layer4)
layer5 = conv_block(layer4, 64) # shape = [batch_size,10,10,30]

flat_layer = Flatten()(layer5) # shape = [batch_size, 3000]
flat_layer = Dropout(.4)(flat_layer)

def dense_block(x, output_dim, act='relu'):
    x = Dense(output_dim, activation=act)(x)
    return BatchNormalization()(x)

layer6 = dense_block(flat_layer, 300)
layer7 = dense_block(layer6, 50)

n_labels = 10 # change this number depending on the number of image classes
outputs = dense_block(layer7, n_labels, 'softmax')

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

# Be sure to make your own images and y_trues arrays!
model.fit(x=images,y=y_trues,batch_size=124)
```

If none of this helped, check out a tutorial or try the [fast.ai](http://course.fast.ai/) course. The fast.ai course is probably the best thing in the world, so I'd say start there.

Comment: Thanks for verbose answer. Though I'm looking more for explanation of Keras behaviour rather than deep learning in general. It's unclear how to do structured prediction (more established term than image prediction) with Keras.